# Android: single TextView is null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I just updated my test smartphone from Android 4.1.1 to 4.1.2 and I am getting a `NullPointerException` that didn't show up before.

This is the `onCreate()` and follow up methods. Note that the function `isOnline()` is working well.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        //fillStatusBar(isOnline());
        fillStatusBar(false);

    }

    private void fillStatusBar(boolean isOnline){
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_menu_connection_status);
        if(isOnline){
            //if(txt != null){
                txt.setBackgroundColor(0xFF78AB46); // NullPointerException!!!
                txt.setText("online");  
            //}
        }else{
            // TODO also an alert
            txt.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF08080);
            txt.setText("offline");
        }
    }
```

In activity_menu.xml (example, the first button here is shown normally):

```
<!-- (...) -->
<TextView style="@style/MainButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:text="@string/info"
        android:onClick="onClickInfo"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_menu_connection_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dip"
        />
```

I commented the line in which the `NullPointerException` gets thrown. If I make the check `if(txt != null)`, no exception is thrown and the layout is showed normally WITHOUT the single `TextView`. How is this even possible? What can I provide additionally to evaluate this case?

Following an image of the LogCat. The log disappears after a few seconds, also when saving the log it is empty.

[image]

Comment: Can you also provide the logcat?

Comment: I don't see a reason why `txt` is null. Are you calling `fillStatusBar()` some other than the activity?

Comment: try using the txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF78AB46"));

Comment: that was it! Can you maybe explain this behaviour?